# webpack config that excludes all node_modules except one

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, babeljs

I am working on a react app that uses [`skpm`](https://github.com/skpm/skpm) and [`react-sketchapp`](https://github.com/airbnb/react-sketchapp). I am importing a node module that uses ES.Next [syntax](https://gist.github.com/pcooney10/e2e699549e47284f3eae8aca390c2148), so I need to use `babel` to parse that modules directory (`node_modules/react-native-calendars` ).

[`skpm`](https://github.com/skpm/skpm) acts as the packager for the app, and uses webpack with `babel-loader`. The webpack config file in skpm is set to exclude the `node_modules` directory. As such, I am getting a build error in the `node_modules/react-native-calendars` directory.

I think I can provide a `webpack.config.js` file in the root of my project that overrides the `node_modules` exlcude for `node_modules/react-native-calendars`.

In modules / rules I originally had:

```
include: (/node_modules\/react-native-calendars/),
exclude: (/node_modules/),
```

but I think I need something like:

```
exclude: new RegExp (/node_modules\/(?!(react-native-calendars))/),
```

Here is the entire `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: new RegExp (/node_modules\/(?!(react-native-calendars))/),
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
            plugins: ['transform-runtime', 'transform-class-properties']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

And here is a link to the **repo** (only two short files in /src and a webpack config) : https://github.com/pcooney10/rn-calendar.

**EDIT**
I have changed the test from `/\.jsx$/` to `/\.jsx?$/`, which is a step in the right direction, but now it seems that none of the imports in `/node_modules/react-native-calendars` are working. I am getting pages of logs that say `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'SomeModule'` and `Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration`.

**EDIT 2**:
Do I need some sort of `path.resolve(__dirname,..)` statement?

Comment: Your `test` is explicitly for `.jsx` files, but you say you want to process `.js`. Is that your issue?

Comment: @loganfsmyth I was working off of [this example](https://github.com/skpm/skpm/blob/master/lib/utils/webpackConfig.js#L46), which uses `.jsx` instead of `.js`. When I switch it to `.js`, I get a whole slew of errors that say my modules can't be found.

Comment: Here is a [discussion](https://github.com/skpm/skpm/issues/53) of the issue on github, it may provide some context is helpful. @loganfsmyth

Comment: Are your files `.js` or `.jsx`? `/\.jsx?$/` would cover both. I don't really think there is enough info in the question to answer this.

Comment: They are .js. Here is a link to a [repo](https://github.com/pcooney10/rn-calendar) where you can reproduce the issue, I have also updated my original question to be a bit more descriptive.

Comment: What errors do you get when you use the regex I posted above?

Comment: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'SomeModule'` and `Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration` @loganfsmyth

Comment: hey @loganfsmyth, do you have anymore thoughts on this? The full error printout of what I'm seeing is here: https://gist.github.com/pcooney10/0d3fbb7612a38cf4a78cb4f85cd0c486

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do that:

```
{  
  test: /\.jsx?$/,  
  exclude: /node_modules\/(?!THIS_MODULE|ANOTHER_MODULE)\/).*/
}
```

Comment: exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,